# quick sort is slower than merge sort

Tags: quicksort

I think the speed of quick sort is less efficient when arranging an array with duplicate data, right? when datatype is char, the bigger the array(over 100000), the closer it gets to the n^2 order.
and assuming there is no duplicate data, to get the best case of a quick sort where the first element is placed as a pivot, first elementsI think we can recursively change the first and intermediate elements by dividing the already aligned array like a merge sort. right? is there general best case?

Comment: The first statement is false for good implementations. It's always `O(n log n)`. What's your question again?

Comment: @dyukha - without using a hybrid sort, such as intro sort (insertion sort + quick sort, the overhead of a pure quick sort with a worst case time complexity of O(n log(n)), such as using [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), causes it to be slower than merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

Lomuto partition scheme, which scans from one end to the other during partition, is slower with duplicates. If all the values are the same, then each partition step splits it into sizes 1 and n-1, a worst case scenario.

Hoare partition scheme, which scans from both both ends towards each other until the indexes (or iterators or pointers) cross, is usually faster with duplicates. Even though duplicates result in more swaps, each swap occurs just after reading and comparing two values to the pivot and are still in the cache for the swap (assuming object size is not huge). As the number of duplicates increases, the splitting improves towards the ideal case where each partition step splits the data into two equal halves. I ran a benchmark sorting 16 million 64 bit integers: with random data, it took about 1.37 seconds, improving with duplicates and with all values the same, it took about about 0.288 seconds.

Another alternative is a 3 way partition, which splits a partition into elements < pivot, elements == pivot, elements > pivot. If all the elements are the same, it's done in O(n) time. For n elements with only k possible values, then time complexity is O(n ⌈log3(k)⌉), and since k is constant, the time complexity is still O(n).

Wiki links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem